# Activate desktop on press of WIN+D

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on windows form application containing two forms. One gets hidden on click of other. Only one form is visible at a time.
I have disabled the Win+D keys for both of them. Used following code for that

```
ntPtr hprog = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(NativeMethods.FindWindow("Progman", "Program Manager"),
IntPtr.Zero, "SHELLDLL_DefView", ""),
IntPtr.Zero, "SysListView32", "FolderView");
NativeMethods.SetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_HWNDPARENT, hprog);
```

But when I press Win+D the desktop gets disabled , to activate the desktop I need to press Win+D once more. This is happening for both the forms. Can you justify the cause of this? I need the desktop active all the time whether the form is opened or closed. This is happening on some PCs only not on all PCs. I am working on Windows 7 and Dot NEt 4.0.

Comment: "Can you justify the cause of this?" You're intercepting system-wide keyboard shortcuts using undocumented native calls.

Comment: @BoltClock: actually this is desktop widget like application so I dont want it to be minimzed.

Comment: @KingCronus: I have tried TopMost=true, MinimizeBox=false . Is there any other way to do this? Plz tell me.

Comment: Not really. What OS version are you targeting? If Vista or Windows 7 there is a framework for desktop widgets. In Windows 8 widgets have been depreciated so I don't see why you would want to create one.

Comment: I agree with @KingCronus.  Winforms is for making winforms.  Trying to make a widget/gadget with winforms is just plain using the wrong tool.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "the desktop gets disabled" I thought thats exactly what you wanted?  We need more information about the version of .NET you are using, the operating system you are trying to use, various other little but very important details.

Comment: @KingCronus:I know that widgets should not be developed using windows form. I can not use other options. I am working on Windows 7.I know the framework for gadgets in it. But i have to use Windows form.

Comment: @Ramhound: Desktop gets disabled means I can not click on dekstop. Neither left nor right click works on desktop. Like it gets freezed. I am working on Windows 7, dot net 4.0.

Comment: @SagarWakchaure - Update your question with that information.  If somebody has the answer to your problem they shouldn't have to search for that important and vital information in a bunch of different comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a practice you want to get in the habit of. A very large number of users use the windows key shortcuts and I do not mean just the computer savy. My wife is a nurse and she uses some of them.

You are trying to change the default behavior of windows for everyone who uses your app and this is only a good idea when you are creating native apps for "locked down" systems. If the environment doesn't allow the use of the windows key shortcuts then you can change them.

Trying to force users to do things is never the right idea.

Comment: I'd like to add to this. If you are creating a native app for a "locked down" system, *please* use Windows Embedded and not vanilla Windows. It allows you to have keyboard filters to prevent these issues. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273235(v=winembedded.21).aspx

Comment: @KingCronus: Nice feature introduced by windows but can not use that also. Thanks for sharing.